# Masked Decimal Input Allow Negative Values

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using a Converter class to mask decimal input. It's working great, but I need to allow for negative entered values.

How can I modify this code to accept negative values?

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Decimal.Parse(value.ToString()).ToString("#0.00");
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string valueFromString = Regex.Replace(value.ToString(), @"\D", "");

            if (valueFromString.Length <= 0)
                return 0m;

            long valueLong;
            if (!long.TryParse(valueFromString, out valueLong))
                return 0m;

            if (valueLong <= 0)
                return 0m;

            return valueLong / 100m;
        }
```

Comment: What happens when you enter a negative value?  Where does it fail?

Comment: It converts it to the positive value. I believe I need to alter the Regex statement.

Comment: have you stepped through each line of code in the debugger to determine exactly where the problem occurs?

Comment: Yes, this line is removing the "-" symbol: string `valueFromString = Regex.Replace(value.ToString(), @"\D", "");`

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of ways you could tackle this - one being

```
bool isNeg = value.ToString().Trim().StartsWith("-");

...

if (isNeg)
  return -1 * valueLong / 100m;
else
  return valueLong / 100m;
```